# Can't connect Android Studio with SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, android-studio, logging, jdbc

I am trying to connect my android studio application with my database to save the "Log in" that are made on the page.

The problem is that when you press "Register" the app freezes for a few seconds and stops. I would appreciate any help.

```
package com.example.trainer;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText edtNombres,edtCorreo;
Button btnAgrgar;

String ip="192.168.1.137",port="51896",db="Trainer",username="IVAN",password="ivanlo";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edtNombres = findViewById(R.id.edtNombres);
    edtCorreo = findViewById(R.id.edtCorreo);
    btnAgrgar = findViewById(R.id.btnAgregarUsuario);

    btnAgrgar.setOnClickListener(View -> agregarUsuario());

}

public Connection conexionBD(){
    Connection conexion=null;
    String ConnectURL=null;
    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        ConnectURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+ip+":"+port+";"+"databasename="+db+";user"+username+";"+"password="+password+";";
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectURL);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return conexion;
}

public void agregarUsuario() {
    try {
        PreparedStatement pat = conexionBD().prepareStatement("insert into usuarios values (?,?)");
        pat.setString(1,edtNombres.getText().toString());
        pat.setString(2,edtCorreo.getText().toString());
        pat.executeUpdate();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"REGISTRO AGREGADO",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

for the connection I use my IP and the credentials that I have created in SQL server.

when I press the button, these errors appear in the Log:

```
2021-08-31 12:54:53.812 7595-7595/com.example.trainer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.trainer, PID: 7595
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/ietf/jgss/GSSManager;
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.createGssToken(TdsCore.java:4400)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.sendMSLoginPkt(TdsCore.java:1971)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:617)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:371)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:236)
    at com.example.trainer.MainActivity.conexionBD(MainActivity.java:43)
    at com.example.trainer.MainActivity.agregarUsuario(MainActivity.java:52)
    at com.example.trainer.MainActivity.lambda$onCreate$0$MainActivity(MainActivity.java:31)
    at com.example.trainer.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~tRgfQFqCq4697lIpnn8MFQ==/com.example.trainer-H6Semqa_egRWQ15HhPsALw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~tRgfQFqCq4697lIpnn8MFQ==/com.example.trainer-H6Semqa_egRWQ15HhPsALw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.createGssToken(TdsCore.java:4400) 
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.sendMSLoginPkt(TdsCore.java:1971) 
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:617) 
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:371) 
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184) 
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580) 
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:236) 
    at com.example.trainer.MainActivity.conexionBD(MainActivity.java:43) 
    at com.example.trainer.MainActivity.agregarUsuario(MainActivity.java:52) 
    at com.example.trainer.MainActivity.lambda$onCreate$0$MainActivity(MainActivity.java:31) 
    at com.example.trainer.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: *"The problem is that when you press "Register" the app freezes for a few seconds and stops"* that very likely isn't going to help us help you. You need to capture the error(s) generated and then add them to your question using the [edit] feature. there are so many reasons why the connection fails, and without *something* we have no idea what.

Comment: One thing I can tell without the error is that I think you're confusing two different connection string formats. With the driver you're using, you specify the database name using a slash, not with a `databaseName` attribute. Ie: `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.136/Trainer;user=IVAN;password=IVAN;`

Comment: I add the error message in the post.The string ConnectionURL was edited too, i add the port.